# cordova build to *.ipa

Tags: ios, cordova, build, ipa

Trying to create *.ipa file by files that generate cordova. Found useful this manual [Automating a cordova ios build](http://maruhgar.blogspot.com/2014/05/automating-cordova-ios-build.html). So first of all i do such commands:

```
cordova create <folder-name> <package-name> <app-name> 
cordova platform add ios
```

Then when i try to execute this command

```
cordova build ios --device
```

I got this errors

> Code Sign error: No matching codesigning identity found: No
>   codesigning identiti es (i.e. certificate and private key pairs)
>   matching “iPhone Developer” were fou nd. CodeSign error: code signing
>   is required for product type 'Application' in SDK ' iOS 7.1'
>
> ** BUILD FAILED **

What i`m doing wrong? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You need a Developer certificate from Apple. Have you been enrolled..?

Comment: Thanks, my guess confirmed. I did not work with apple software before, that`s why i didn`t know about this.

Comment: Phonegap can be a way to avoid having enrolled, you do not upload a ipa file, but a phonegap project that the deploy in a generic wrapper that is published on AppleStore.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I think that i need to get apple dev certificate. This is due with work of my php app, it works thru cli with mac server. End user must have *.ipa files.